# Compiling with DMD on 64bit Linux or Linking with 32bit object files

Tags: 64-bit, linker, 32-bit, d, dmd

What is the best way to compile programs with DMD on a 64bit machine? It doesn't need to compile to 64Bit code. I know about GDC, but want to work with D2 also. There is also chroot, but am hoping for a simpler way.

The actual problem isn't with compiling, but linking. DMD calls on GCC to perform linking with system libraries. Could I get DMD to have GCC link against 32bit library? Or how would I do it manually?

I already have the ia32 libraries installed which is why I can run DMD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask GCC to perform 32-bit link by passing it `'-m32'` flag.

It appears that `DMD` doesn't invoke `gcc` to perform the link, but rather invokes `ld` directly. The equivalent `ld` switch is `'-melf_i386'`, and apparently the way to make `DMD` pass that option to the linker is with `'-L-melf_i386'` flag.

Note that many systems separate runtime and development libraries. 32-bit runtime packages are almost always installed by default, but 32-bit development packages may not be.

You need *development* 32-bit packages to build 32-bit programs. The fact that 32-bit `DMD` can run does not in itself prove that you have all the 32-bit libraries you need in order to build 32-bit programs.

Comment: Thank you. And to complete the answer, The needed package for development is gcc-multilib. Also the switch I used was -melf_i386 and to have dmd forward to gcc -L-melf_i386. Could you update your answer?